# VMWare Workstation connected to ESXi only shows partial screen

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-workstation

I am currently connected remotely to my ESXi 6.0.0 server.  I have a virtual machine on it that I have no problem using RDP to get to.  However, when I run it via VMWare Workstation 12.5.2 build-4638234 - it only shows me the upper left portion of the screen.

Here are the 2 images that show exactly what is happening:

- VMWare Workstation

  [image: VMWare Workstation - Full Screen Image]
- RDP

  [image: RDP - Full Screen Image]

Now - the reason I NEED to run inside VMWare Workstation is because I am using a VPN inside of the image to connect to a customer who uses Cisco VPN.  If I connect via RDP, it will shut off my RDP session.  With Workstation - I don't have that issue.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting/changing any of the Display options in Preferences?

Comment: Display options in windows?  I don't see a lot of options for the video card in the virtual image settings, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: In VMware Workstation, go to the Edit menu, select Preferences, select Display, try changing some of the options.

Comment: yes, I tried multiple settings.  Couldn't find any that worked.

Comment: Are you running workstation under Windows or Linux? On a side note - what you said about cisco VPN is correct, however you can replace Cisco VPN client with the vpnc or Shrewsoft VPN. Both will let you run your tunnel in a split tunnel mode, so you will not loose your rdp connection.

Comment: Also check this https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_running_display_fitting_host.html "If you update VMware Tools without powering off and powering on suspended virtual machines, and then attempt to resize the guest, the display will be corrupted". This is for an old version, but perhaps something of this nature goes on here. Did you try to reboot your VM?

Comment: And have you tried connecting to your VM console with the VMware vSphere client? This client is after all more suitable for working with ESXi hosts and vCenters. Perhaps you won't have same issue with the different client.

Comment: You may want to try using VMware Remote Console instead.

Comment: From when you are facing this issue? Have you done any VMware tools update.

Comment: Sorry for delaying on this one... I am running under Windows.  I'm not a fan of the console at all to be honest, which is why I use Workstation.  I resolved the issue by going backwards in versions from 12.5.2 to  12.5.1.  That solved the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hints:

- Debug from the VMware vSphere Client, what I recommend you to try (it's free), as it is the natural and proper way to connect to your ESXi, and where you can open also the VMs console. Therefore, from there, **you can see if the problem could be in the VM**.

  - Chose the proper version, as linked from: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2089791
- Install/update/remove and re-install your VMWare tools.

  - I think the better way to install them is from your vSphere Client, as it is connected to your ESXi, and it will mount the tools installer in the VM optical drive. As Workstation would try to mount its tools image to its managed VM, but the VM is on ESXi, I would say that this probably will fail (although I never tested it). Also, in this way, the proper tools for your ESXi version will be installed.
  - You can do it as shown in the screenshot below (taken from
    https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/vmware-tools.html).

    [image]